# CD/DVD-RW Drive not at all reading discs in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, dell, inspiron, cd-drive

My DVD drive is not reading any discs that's put into the drive. Last time, it worked like some miracle happened and now, it isn't.

```
OS:Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Device: Dell Inspiron N5050 (Ubuntu Version)
```

I'm a new Ubuntu user and I really need help from you guys :)
Thank you.

Comment: If it indeed does not read ANY disc, music/dvd/data, factory burned/self burned... then you should serously consider the drive is dead.

Comment: See if you can boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD. If you can, at least you could probably say that the drive is working. If it's real dusty, blow out the DVD drive and try other disks again.

Comment: But it detected a disc yesterday. Gosh, I'm very confused. It shows CD/DVD-RW Drive in disks app

Comment: Strange, it worked again yesterday after I tried ejecting and re-inserting the disc after blowing the DVD Drive (thanks @heynnema for the suggestion) after that, the drive, now works fine and the CD is detected. I tried ejecting and re-inserting it again to make sure and no problems shown at all. It shows CD/DVD Drive in File Manager. 
_I guess, it is fixed now. I will catch up later if the trouble comes back_

Comment: @Harizone please remember to vote/accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the comments...

See if you can boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD. If you can, at least you could probably say that the drive is working. If it's real dusty, blow out the DVD drive and try other disks again.

**Update:**

After blowing out the DVD drive to remove any dust, the drive now seems to be working.